# Install module from URL to site directory instead of /all

Tags: 7, installation

At http://drupal.local/admin/modules/install, when I install modules by entering a URL, they get saved to sites/all/modules.  I have a multisite setup, and I need them to go to sites/SITE/modules.

Any way to control that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update manager will only install modules to `sites/all/modules` unfortunately (see [this](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/update) page), so it looks like you'll have to FTP/SCP/whatever them to your server.

There are some advanced installation methods [here](http://drupal.org/node/346385), but installing modules into specific directories is not something the update manager can do.

Alternatively, you should definately try [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) if you're not using it already.  There's a pretty good tutorial on how to set up Drush for a multisite [here](http://www.pixelclever.com/how-set-up-drush-for-multisite-installation).

[Drush homepage](http://drush.ws/)

[Drush project page](http://drupal.org/project/drush)

[Drush DO page](http://drupal.org/node/477684)

[Drush cheatsheet](http://drupal.org/files/drush-cheat-sheet.pdf)

[Drush guide](http://drupal.org/files/drushguide2012.pdf)

Comment: This is for a Drupal class I'm teaching.  We're trying to keep things simple, so students can focus on the fun parts of Drupal, without worrying about site directories, permissions, ftp, etc.

Sounds like a multisite install just won't work, I'll just do a bunch of drupal directories.